# How to fail a test if no error is thrown in jest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, feathersjs

i'm currently improving the branch/function coverage of our `feathers.js/node.js` api (testing with `jest`).
Currently there is a service with a property which should only accept certain values, which is not implemented yet.

Valid values would be something like:

```js
const validValues = ["System", "Engineering", "Production"]
```

If one of the values is provided, the api should accept the request and return a valid response.

If a value like

```js
const invalidValue = ["Some", "Invalid", "Value"]
```

is provided, the API should reject the request.

Since value validation is not implemented yet, the idea was to implement a test which fails if invalid values like which are accepted by the api and it is ensured that the api only accepts valid values.

```js
it("test service for invalid values", async () => {
    const invalidValues = ["Some", "Invalid", "Value"];

    invalidValues.map(async (invalidValue) => {
      await expect(async () => {
        await app.service("release-types").create({
          someProperty: "some Value"
          propertyWithValueConstraint: invalidValue,
        });
      }).rejects.toThrow();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `[].map` does not run asynchronously and therefore does not catch the assertions. You have two options:

1. Use [await Promise.all(promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
it("test service for invalid values", async () => {
  const invalidValues = ["Some", "Invalid", "Value"];

  await Promise.all(invalidValues.map(async (invalidValue) => {
    await expect(async () => {
      await app.service("release-types").create({
        someProperty: "some Value"
        propertyWithValueConstraint: invalidValue,
      });
    }).rejects.toThrow();
  }));
});
```

2. Use a [for ... of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
it("test service for invalid values", async () => {
  const invalidValues = ["Some", "Invalid", "Value"];

  for (const invalidValue of invalidValues) {
    await expect(async () => {
      await app.service("release-types").create({
        someProperty: "some Value"
        propertyWithValueConstraint: invalidValue,
      });
    }).rejects.toThrow();
  }
});
```